# Unable to convert string in to number in Jupyter

Tags: jupyter-notebook

***Here is my code:***

```
def str2number(amount):
 if type(amount) == int:
    return amount
    
 if amount[-1] == 'M': d = float(amount[:-1])
 return d*1000000
        
 elif amount[-1] == 'K': d = float(amount[:-1])
 return d*1000
    
 else: d = float(amount[:])
    return d
    
FIFA18['ValueNum'] = FIFA18['Value'].apply(lambda x: str2number(x))
FIFA18['WageNum'] = FIFA18['Wage'].apply(lambda x: str2number(x))
```

---

***Here is the error code:***

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 15         return d
> 16
> ---> 17 FIFA18['ValueNum'] = FIFA18['Value'].apply(lambda x: str2number(x))
> 18 FIFA18['WageNum'] = FIFA18['Wage'].apply(lambda x: str2number(x))
>
> c:\users\brain\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py
> in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)    4136
> else:    4137                 values = self.astype(object)._values
> -> 4138                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)    4139     4140         if len(mapped) and
> isinstance(mapped[0], Series):
>
> pandas_libs\lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()
>
> in (x)
> 15         return d
> 16
> ---> 17 FIFA18['ValueNum'] = FIFA18['Value'].apply(lambda x: str2number(x))
> 18 FIFA18['WageNum'] = FIFA18['Wage'].apply(lambda x: str2number(x))
>
> in str2number(amount)
> 12
> 13     else:
> ---> 14         d = float(amount[:])
> 15         return d
> 16
>
> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '� 0.00'

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that this part is correct?

```
    else:
        d = float(amount[:])
        return d
```

You are assuming that everything else is just a number but your dataset contains some other characters. You need to clean your dataset first or change the function to account for those cases too.

Comment: @Yomibrain, by amount[:-1] you are removing the last characters but some values in your dataset contain non-numeric values in the beginning. Instead of amount[:-1] you can do re.sub(r'\D', '', amount) which will remove every non-numeric character (you need to import re first).

Comment: Seriously i don't understand what you mean, can i share my desktop of project file with you?

Comment: @Yomibrain, I'm a new user too. It turns out you can't write private messages here hence we can't share zoom links. Can you try [this](https://onecompiler.com/python/3wxrtz7nd) version of the function?